# Is it possible to allow my clients to create AdWords ads on their accounts, via my system which is connected to the AdWords API?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have a 'landing page creator' system which my clients use to create their own landing pages.

I would like to know if it's possible to integrate the AdWords API to my system, and allow my clients to create ads directly to their AdWords account via the admin I've built?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, yes. There already are apps using AdWords API like Marin software, Wordstream, Altus etc.

For comprehensive overview of the tools available, see [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-software-to-automate-Adwords-PPC).

There are also some limits of [AdWords API usage](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/rate-limits).

I also belive that this broad question might be Googled next time.